# Get Position on zooming in map : leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am fairly new in using leaflet. Can someone tell me that can I get longitude and latitude of the area where I have finished zooming? and How can I know how many objects are in that area?

Comment: What do you mean by "objects"? Do you mean markers?

Comment: Yes I mean markers

Comment: `map.on('zoomend', function(){ console.log(map.getBounds()); });`. Iterate through your geographical features to check whether they're inside the bounds, or make a spatial index (with e.g. [rbush](https://github.com/mourner/rbush)) if you need to handle lots of big queries.

Comment: @Developer check out my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to catch `zoomend` event, inside an event object will be map instance, from which you can get boundingBox.
Then for you check each layer is it inside bbox.

```
map.on('zoomend',function(e){
  var map = e.target,
  bounds = map.getBounds();
  map.eachLayer(function(layer){
    if(bounds.contains(layer.getBounds()))
      alert('kek');
  }); 
})
```

Comment: bounds.contains is showing error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined"

Comment: Get bounds only for polygonal layers, for markers you need to use getLatLng()

Comment: Started Working Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have an [L.map](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-usage) object called `map`. In this case `map.getBounds()` will return you an [o.LatLngBounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds) object, which has a `_southWest` and a `_northEast` member. These are defining the left-bottom and right-top geographic points of the bounding rectangle. If you have a set of markers, then iterating the set of markers and checking whether they are inside the bounds looks like this:

```
function getMarkersInside(bounds, markers) {
    var subset = [];
    for (var markerIndex in markers) {
        if ((markers[markerIndex].lat >= bounds._northEast.lat) && (markers[markerIndex].lat <= bounds._southWest.lat) && (markers[markerIndex].lon >= bounds._northEast.lon) && (markers[markerIndex].lon <= bounds._southWest.lon)) {
            subset.push(markers[markerIndex]);
        }
    }
    return subset;
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
var markersInside = getMarkersInside(map.getBounds(), myMarkers);
```

Make sure you do this on `zoomend`.